# UITest fails with error 'ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture x86_64'

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am new to Xcode and Swift. I just tried to create UITest using swift language. I I get this build failed with the error when I try to run the simple test that just print the "Hello world"::

> "ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Is anyone having the same issue? I appreciate if you can share how to fix it. BTW I am using Xcode 9.1 and Swift 4

Answer (score 11):

Step to Fix:

1. Select your Project
2. Go to Target -> Select your Test target
3. then go to Build Setting -> Search Mach-O Type
4. Change to -> Bundle

[image]

Comment: This does nothing